# [DataType(DataType.Date)]

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a date field and I want to use the above date annotation.  Normally you would include this in the model, above the date property  like below:

```
 [DataType(DataType.Date)]
 public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

But since my database is already build I have generated the entity model directly from the database.

And of course, the cs files generated by the entity model suggest, not the modify the code as these files are auto generated.

Any idea on how to set the date type annotation for a DateTime column in this situation?

Thanks

Joe

Comment: Sounds like you used model first. Why do you need to add the attribute, your not using code-first...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use DB-first, you can do this in one of two ways:

- Use a [metadata "buddy class"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141.aspx).
- Write a [dedicated view model](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/12/31/38500/), and project onto that.

I prefer the second solution, as it allows the presentation and entity model to evolve independently.

Comment: Thanks Craig, I was wondering about partial classes, But I like the dedicated view model idea. Joe